# jquery tools : Configure tabs with ajax to change title

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

I'm using [jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html) with the Tab feature and Ajax support to link to pages. My problem is that I want to change the title of the page when the tab is changed.

I can't find any references on the guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("title").text(title);
```